# How to send parameters from master report to chart (Line graph) in Jasper?

Tags: charts, jasper-reports

I am generating a report having a table and a Line graph.
The master report dataset returns 8 records. So, I need 8 pages with each page displaying data for each record. I have mapped the field from master dataset to both the table and line graph's dataset.

The table is displayed 8 times perfectly with the correct param value.
But, the line graph always shows data for the last parameter value.

Jrxml Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="chart" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="66962ca4-5579-453f-a9fe-5d7284566dc1">
    <subDataset name="chartDS" uuid="74b2bdf1-5e99-43ec-94c6-f6c999ea449c">
        <parameter name="deviceId" class="java.lang.Long"/>
        <queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[SELECT 
    ticket.descr,
    IFNULL(SUM(diff)/60, 0) as duration,
    DATE(ticket.created_date) as date
FROM
    (SELECT 
        t.id, t.created_date, t.restored_date, E.descr,TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.created_date,t.restored_date) as diff
    FROM
        ticket t
    Inner JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
        description AS descr
    FROM
        alarm_config
    WHERE
        enabled = 1
            AND site_location_device_id  =   $P{deviceId} ) E ON t.description LIKE CONCAT('%', E.descr, '%')
        AND t.site_location_device_id  =  $P{deviceId} 
    ORDER BY E.descr) ticket
GROUP BY ticket.descr, DATE(ticket.created_date)
ORDER BY DATE(ticket.created_date)]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="descr" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="duration" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <field name="date" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT 
    sl.location_name,sld.id as deviceId ,sld.name
FROM
    site
        INNER JOIN
    site_location sl ON site.id = sl.site_id
        INNER JOIN
    site_location_device sld ON sl.id = sld.site_location_id

 where  site_id = 32   and sld.device_type_id = (SELECT id FROM device_type WHERE name LIKE 'HSS')
]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="location_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="deviceId" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="273" splitType="Stretch">
            <barChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="20" y="23" width="514" height="200" uuid="53f820c6-7e46-4052-bcdf-65d3a4b9cf15"/>
                    <chartTitle>
                        <titleExpression><![CDATA[$F{deviceId}]]></titleExpression>
                    </chartTitle>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="chartDS" uuid="94e17f1e-b5a7-4b22-9864-481fc0adf56b">
                            <datasetParameter name="deviceId">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{deviceId}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{descr}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{duration}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot labelRotation="54.0"/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat labelRotation="54.0">
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

PS: Both table and graph are in the detail section.
Also, I am trying this from eclipse - report designer plugin

Comment: please share the jrxml file

Comment: @Rathnayake - Updated the question.It has only a bar graph.

Comment: what is the last parameter?

Comment: Issue here is with deviceId parameter.The master dataset has a field deviceId which is passed as a param to the chart.There is no issue with graph rendering.Only thing is deviceId param is always same and its last value in dataset

Comment: please review the 2nd `queryString`. you passed `site_id = 32` in this query and some times it returned same value for `deviceId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to solve the problem.
The issue was with the evaluation time of the chart's expression.

It was by mistake set to "Report".I changed it to "Now".

Replaced this 
`<chart evaluationTime="Report">`

with below 
`<chart evaluationTime="Now">`

**evaluationTime** − Determines when the chart's expression will be evaluated. Values could be Now, Report, Page, Column, Group, Band. The default value is Now